# Oracle Case Statement

Tags: oracle

Consider this table below and the result set is also given. Now, how do I get only one record as soon as one of the conditions is satisfied.

```
SQL> SELECT ename
  2  ,      job
  3  ,      CASE
  4            WHEN sal < 1000
  5            THEN 'Low paid'
  6            WHEN sal BETWEEN 1001 AND 2000
  7            THEN 'Reasonably well paid'
  8            WHEN sal BETWEEN 2001 AND 3001
  9            THEN 'Well paid'
 10            ELSE 'Overpaid'
 11         END AS pay_status
 12  FROM   emp;

ENAME      JOB       PAY_STATUS
---------- --------- --------------------
SMITH      CLERK     Low paid
ALLEN      SALESMAN  Reasonably well paid
WARD       SALESMAN  Reasonably well paid
JONES      MANAGER   Well paid
MARTIN     SALESMAN  Reasonably well paid
BLAKE      MANAGER   Well paid
CLARK      MANAGER   Well paid
SCOTT      ANALYST   Well paid
KING       PRESIDENT Overpaid
TURNER     SALESMAN  Reasonably well paid
ADAMS      CLERK     Reasonably well paid
JAMES      CLERK     Low paid
FORD       ANALYST   Well paid
MILLER     CLERK     Reasonably well paid
```

Comment: you can use `rownum` function

Comment: that might work, but what if the first condition fails (i.e) no records are present for this condn, the second condition passes and should return only the second row and so on.

Comment: `ROWNUM` would randomly return just limited records out of the entire resultset. However, OP wants the `DISTINCT` rows for each condition.

Comment: Assuming the result set you gave is not what you wish for, could you detail the result set you expect.

Answer (score 0):

To get only one record for each condition satisfied, apply `DISTICT` in the `SELECT` statement.

`SQL> SELECT DISTINCT ename
  2  ,      job
  3  ,      CASE
  4            WHEN sal < 1000
  5            THEN 'Low paid'
  6            WHEN sal BETWEEN 1001 AND 2000
  7            THEN 'Reasonably well paid'
  8            WHEN sal BETWEEN 2001 AND 3001
  9            THEN 'Well paid'
 10            ELSE 'Overpaid'
 11         END AS pay_status
 12  FROM   emp;`